# Not able to edit other posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Today I met with a problem here. Actually I was trying to edit some questions today. I used to get a "Thanks for your edit" message. But today when I edited a few posts I was not able to see that message saying "Thanks for your edit" and even my edit is not being changed. What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you recently had a number of your edits rejected? You might be temporarily unable to submit edits, although you should see a pop-up notification informing you of this.

Comment: Looking at those rejected edits... Sure, none of them were major, but they all improved spelling and/or grammar.  Why were they rejected?  If I see bad punctuation or a lot of lower-case "i"s, I edit the post.

Comment: But I feel that the changes I have made are of typographical conventions and I believe they are correct. Should I not edit these kind of things in general?

Comment: Yes, a couple of them should probably have been accepted. But also consider the date of the post being edited. We don't necessarily want to bump old questions (6 months or more) just to change lowercase "i"s to uppercase. Also note that at least one or two of them were erroneously rejected by the owner of the question. They have the right to do that, of course, even if your edit was actually valid.

Comment: @Andro, also remember suggesting an edit causes several people to have to spend time reviewing it.  Ask yourself "Is this edit urgent/significant enough to have others review it?", and if the answer is no, then let a user with edit privileges fix it later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you must know, you have crossed the threshold for having too many rejected edit suggestions.  You will not be able to submit any more edits until next week (I think).

Here's a few of the suggestions I've been able to dig up:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75636
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75497
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75528
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75539
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74872
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74920
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74989
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74993
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74996
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74565
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74383
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74386
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74474
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74502
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74507
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74538
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74562

All of them have been making little spelling changes to posts.  While commendable, you really should be trying to fix more of the problems with the post hence the rejection by these users.  I would have rejected a lot of them myself too.

---

For example, consider this edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75497

> how to send data from a php page that is open in browser to a particular person who has android set with him.The person is connected to the Internet and me also.i know the person IMEI number.kindly tell me all the possible solutions.please i am new to android

That post is horrible, no doubt about it.  Bad grammar, punctuation, improper English, useless comments.  There was so much more you could have done with the post.  Your edit only dealt with capitalization.  You didn't even include spaces between the sentences.

**Bottom line:** you did not improve the post enough to standards.  You should have fixed as much as you could have.  We wouldn't expect it to be completely perfect in the end, that can be difficult to do and most of us understands that.  But we would expect a lot more effort fixing the post as we would hope for when one asks a question or posts an answer.

You should strongly consider fixing the *whole* post and not just one aspect about it.  Go back through your editing history and see what you did in your accepted posts and the rejected posts (start with these) and ask yourself this: Are there other things I could have fixed in the post?

Comment: Rejecting edits because they didn't fix enough?  This is like firing your dermatologist because he didn't cure your heart disease.   An improvement's an improvement.   But, I suppose that if someone can't see a marked difference, they might reject the change.

Comment: @Brock: Remember that there's a reputation boost involved in having a suggested edit approved. Some people think the edit needs to be substantial enough so as to actually deserve the +2 points. The system already requires that all suggested edits modify at least 6 characters in the original post. The same restrictions don't and shouldn't apply to users with full edit privileges.

Comment: @Brock: I say, leave the minor fixes to those who have earned their right.  Until then, you need to _prove_ to others that you can handle it.  I won't fire a heart surgeon because he wasn't able to cure cancer, but I'd think twice before letting an unqualified person cut me open just because they want to be one.  Besides, how can you possibly think the example I've shown was an improvement?

Comment: @Brock - If you use the review pane to accept or reject suggested edits, some of the linked edits came in bunches. If one user has like 5-10 marginal edits pending, there is a high risk that not all will be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen many of your edits and rejected some.

When you edit, you just replace "i" with "I" and usually that's it, and you leave many other grammar problems unfixed. For example, such sentence:

> > i have problem with XYZ,i really want help tnx

Your typical edit would be:

> > I have problem with XYZ,I really want help tnx

What I would expect (and do myself) is:

> > I have problem with XYZ and I really want help, thanks

This is basic example, but should give you idea of what you're doing wrong.

In addition, there's really no point in fixing grammar of old (year+) posts except for question titles which matters for search - so I automatically reject any grammar fixes of old posts and probably others are doing the same.

Finally, I feel like I owe one final example.. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/75497):

> > how to send data from a php page that is open in browser to a particular person who has android set with him.The person is connected to the Internet and me also.i know the person IMEI number.kindly tell me all the possible solutions.please i am new to android

Should become this if putting the time to edit:

> > How to send data from PHP page that is open in a browser to particular person who has Android set with him?
> >     The person is connected to the Internet and me also.
> >     I know the person `IMEI` number.
> >     Kindly tell me all the possible solutions, thanks.

Just capitalizing the first letter of sentences is NOT enough.

Hope this makes sense to you and looking forward to approve your improved suggested edits when you'll be able to do that again. :)

Comment: I would probably have rejected your edits, especially the first one. No need to leave `and I really want help, thanks` and  `How to send data from PHP page that is open in a browser to particular person who has Android set with him?` is a horrible sentence that would benifit from a rewrita and lastly `Kindly tell me all the possible solutions, thanks.` needs fixin.